# How to reset a click counter?

Tags: android, android-button

I have an implementation where, on every click of a button, a counter is increased and the counter is shown in a `TextView`. There's a reset button that is supposed to set the counter back to 0, so that the count can start again from zero when the `btn_take_photo` button is pressed. Here's my code:

```
private int counter = 0;
btn_take_photo.setOnClickListener(new FloatingActionButton.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                
                counter++;
                count.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }
        });
```

This is the method called by the button (`btn_approve`) that is supposed to reset the counter:

```
 public void btn_aprove (View view)
    {        count.setText("0");

    }
```

When I click `btn_approve`, the `TextView` shows 0. But, when I press `btn_take_photo` again, the counter starts from the last set value instead of 1. For instance, if I reset the counter when `count` is 6, the `TextView` reads 0. Then if I press `btn_take_photo`, the counter shows 6 again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to set the variable `counter` back to 0.

So your "Reset"-function should look like this:

```
public void btn_aprove (View view)
    {        
        count.setText("0");
        counter = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must also reset counter = 0;